# Dependency property not working on a interaction behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I am trying to add a dependency property `IsActive` to a RubberBandBehavior I found on CodeProject, so that I can activate and deactivate it from my ViewModel. The code below does not give any compile error and runs, but the value does not seem to be set correctly, when I check the line with the comment `\\ this line is always 'false'`.

The modified class `RubberBandBehavior`:

```
public class RubberBandBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(RubberBandBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(IsActiveProperty_Changed));

    private static void IsActiveProperty_Changed(DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // This gets called _after_ OnAttached!
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool a = IsActive; // this line is always 'false'

        RubberBandAdorner band = new RubberBandAdorner(AssociatedObject);
        AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AssociatedObject);
        adornerLayer.Add(band);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have this:

```
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:RubberBandBehavior IsActive="True"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

My plan is then to bind to my ViewModel like this, but first I need to get the above sorted out:

```
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:RubberBandBehavior IsActive="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsEditable}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: @Sinatr you are incorrect, the use of Behaviors in this instance is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont get this value in the `AssociatedObject.Loaded` event. You need to use the `IsActiveProperty_Changed` handler in your code example to get the correct value of this property

Comment: Hi. So this works correctly and `args.NewValue` gives the correct value inside `IsActiveProperty_Changed`. However I can not figure out how to then set the property `IsActive` or act on the change in any other way, since `IsActiveProperty_Changed` is static and I cannot access the non-static members/properties. Is there a way around this? Furthermore say I set `IsActive` to "False" in the XAML `IsActiveProperty_Changed` will never be called, since the default init-value of the bool is `False`. How do I act on its value then? I will accept this answer, when I figured out the rest... Thanks!

Comment: OK, your understanding of dependency properties is a little incorrect. IsActiveProperty isnt a bool, its a container for either a value or a binding. If you put IsActive="False" in your XAML then IsActiveProperty_Changed will get callled. If you want to access your behaviour instance then that value is "DependencyObject sender" that you get in IsActiveProperty_Changed - all you need to do is cast is to RubberBandBehavior to get at the instance members

Comment: Thanks for the comment. With it I got it to work. It still required a little fiddling, since the event for `IsActiveProperty_Changed` fires before the `AssociatedObject.Loaded` event, so I had to work around that. But you are definitely right: I will have to read up on how to implement dependency properties. Thanks again!